# SpecFlow+ Runner Server: Unable to find the "server" directory in \packages\SpecRun.Runner.x.y.z\tools

Tags: specflow, specrun

I am currently trying to set up the SpecFlow+ Runner Server by following this instructions: Setting Up The SpecFlow+ Runner Server
I struggle at following point:

> "2. Locate the "server" directory in your solution's
>   `\packages\SpecRun.Runner.x.y.z\tools` directory (created when you
>   install the NuGet package). Copy the contents of the “server”
>   directory to your server."

There is no "server" directory in my solutions `\packages\SpecRun.Runner.3.0.337\tools` directory. I have installed the Nuget SpecRun.SpecFlow.2-4-0. I also tried it with the newest Nuget SpecRun.SpecFlow.3-0-0 (v3.0.337) with the same outcome.

Isn't the "server" directory located in this Nuget anmore? Where can I find it now?

I also asked the question here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/specrun/YyM7YPc6Rbc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Has been answered here: https://groups.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!topic/specrun/YyM7YPc6Rbc

Quote Andreas Willich:

> Because of a bug, we didn't added the SpecFlow+Runner Server files to
>   the NuGet package. We will fix this as soon as possible and upload new
>   packages to NuGet.org.